# Rotating a point in HTML canvas

Tags: javascript, canvas, vector, rotation, transformation

I'm trying to learn some basic vector math, but I can't seem to get this method for rotating a point to work. The magnitude of the rotated vectors is scaling up and I don't know what's up with the angle.

Here's the relevant function. I'm working in javascript/HTML canvas.

```
function rotate(point, center, angle) {
  var theta = (Math.PI / 180) * angle,
      cX = center.pos.x,
      cY = center.pos.y,
      pX = point.pos.x,
      pY = point.pos.y,
      pCos = Math.cos(theta),
      pSin = Math.sin(theta),
      x = pX - cX,
      y = pY - cY;
  x = (x * pCos - y * pSin) + cX;
  y = (x * pSin + y * pCos) + cY;
  return {x: Math.floor(x), y: Math.floor(y)};
}
```

Here's a [jsbin of the weird result](http://jsbin.com/xiresuk/edit?js,output)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The function is almost right but you are just using the modified x value to calculate y

```
function rotate(point, center, angle) {
  var theta = (Math.PI / 180) * angle,
      cX = center.pos.x,
      cY = center.pos.y,
      pX = point.pos.x,
      pY = point.pos.y,
      pCos = Math.cos(theta),
      pSin = Math.sin(theta),
      x = pX - cX,
      y = pY - cY;
  /* You had
  x = (x * pCos - y * pSin) + cX; // you change x on this line
  y = (x * pSin + y * pCos) + cY; /// then used the modified x to get y
  */
  // this will fix the problem
  var xx = (x * pCos - y * pSin) + cX;
  var yy = (x * pSin + y * pCos) + cY;
  return {x: Math.floor(xx), y: Math.floor(yy)};
}
```

Comment: Ah! I knew it had to be something simple like that. Thank you so much for your help.